# Get SVG icons dynamically in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, next.js

I wanted to get SVG icons dynamically. I found a method to do this but it seems I made some mistakes. Where am I doing it wrong?

**Icon.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactComponent as Bollards } from "./icons/bollards.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Earthquake } from "./icons/earthquake.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Fire } from "./icons/fire.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Healthy } from "./icons/heartbeat.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Home } from "./icons/home.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Planting } from "./icons/planting.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Business } from "./icons/suitcase.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Travel } from "./icons/airplane-around-earth.svg";

const iconTypes = {
  bollards: Bollards,
  earthQuake: Earthquake,
  fire: Fire,
  healthy: Healthy,
  home: Home,
  planting: Planting,
  business: Business,
  travel: Travel
};

const IconComponent = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  let Icon = iconTypes[name];
  return <Icon {...props} />;
};

export default IconComponent;
```

**Feautures.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Icon from "./icon";

export default function Features() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon name="bollards" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**I get this error when trying to export icons.**

```
error - ./components/icon.js
Attempted import error: 'ReactComponent' is not exported from './icons/bollards.svg' (imported as 'Bollards').
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [SVGR](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr) that allows us to import SVGs into your React applications as components.

You need to add `@svgr/webpack` as a dependency and modify the `next.config.js` file like this.

`next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
    });
    return config;
  }
};
```

Then, you can simply import your icons without using `ReactComponent`.

`Icon.js`:

```js
import React from "react";

import Bollards from './icons/bollards.svg';
import Earthquake from './icons/earthquake.svg';
import Fire from './icons/fire.svg';
import Healthy from './icons/heartbeat.svg';
import Home from './icons/home.svg';
import Planting from './icons/planting.svg';
import Business from './icons/suitcase.svg';
import Travel from './icons/airplane-around-earth.svg';

const iconTypes = {
  bollards: Bollards,
  earthQuake: Earthquake,
  fire: Fire,
  healthy: Healthy,
  home: Home,
  planting: Planting,
  business: Business,
  travel: Travel
};

const IconComponent = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  let Icon = iconTypes[name];
  return <Icon {...props} />;
};

export default IconComponent;
```

Working demo is [available on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-icons-278et).

Comment: It works. Thank you so much for taking your precious time and helping.